# Code breaks when inserting values into database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I was wondering what went wrong with my SQL code, it broke every time I run it.

```
    $link = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'usr', 'password', 'db_name');

    $item_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['item_des']);
    $item_price = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['price']);
    $item_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['date']);

    $query = "INSERT INTO item(item_name, item_price, item_date) VALUES ('".$item_name."', '".$item_price."', '"$item_date"') ";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if ($result) {
        echo 'Success';
    }
```

Comment: Missing concatenation at the end of the query string. Syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in (concatenation at the end):

```
  $query = "INSERT INTO item(item_name, item_price, item_date) VALUES ('".$item_name."', '".$item_price."', '"$item_date"') ";
```

Should be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO item(item_name, item_price, item_date) VALUES ('" . $item_name . "', '" . $item_price. "', '" . $item_date . "') ";
```

Comment: thank you for the answer I forgot that two small periods